# robot_upstart: nodes don't work well

Tags: ros, robot-upstart, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use robot_upstart to start the robot.In the startup.launch file ,I launch only one node which I called `myrobot_node` . Here is the node content.[image: image description]. In this node, l launch a launchfile. However , I can see all nodes are running when I use`rosnode list`.But when I test the nodes , I find some are not working well .For example , in one node,
I use `system("echo 666666 | sudo -S reboot")` to reboot the system .However ,it didn't respond. And if I `rosrun robot_upstart myrobot_node` directly,things seems ok. what's wrong ? is there any problem with the function `system()`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285918/robot_upstart:-nodes-don%27t-work-well/) by [Tomas yuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29377/tomas-yuan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2018-03-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-19**:
Please don't use a screenshot to post text. Images are not searchable and people cannot copy and paste your code from an image. Please update your question with a copy and paste (using the preformatted text `101010` button). http://wiki.ros.org/Support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not really an answer though,

> if I `rosrun robot_upstart myrobot_node` directly,things seems ok.

I don't think an executable called `myrobot_node` is available in [robot_upstart](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_upstart) package. On my computer I see:

```
$ rosrun robot_upstart  (here I press tab)
getifip       install       mklaunch      mkxacro       mutate_files  uninstall     
$ apt-cache policy ros-kinetic-robot-upstart 
ros-kinetic-robot-upstart:
  Installed: 0.2.2-0xenial-20180222-231517-0800
```

So, I can only assume you're using cutomized version of `robot_upstart`. If that's the case, no one can't really help you unless we have an access to its code (and even if we do have an access, looking at the cutomized code raises a bar for most of the people on this forum in general, so that the chance of you getting useful response will get slim).

That said, please try to make your question as general as possible. Then, share all the commands you ran and the output regarding installation you did using `robot_upstart`. Also the entire launch file where you include the node you cited.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2018-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1